# How to find the count of character in the Text Area Field in OmniScrpt salesforce

Tags: vlocity, omniscript

I want to get the count of character in the Text Area Field using omniscript in salesforce.

```
COUNT(%TextArea1%)!=''
```

I used the formula to get the count but unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get the value of the text area field
String text = {!Text_Area_Field__c};
// Get the length of the text
Integer count = text.length();
// Display the count on the screen
ScreenElement.displayMessage('The number of characters is ' + count);
```

This code will get the value of the text area field, calculate its length, and display it on the screen.

I used the OmniScripts Text Area Element [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.os_omniscripts_text_area_element.htm&language=en_US&type=5) and the How to do a character count in rich text field [forum post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/248513/how-to-do-character-count-in-rich-text-field) as references.

PS:

- Open the OmniScript Designer by opening an OmniScript via the OmniStudio app.
- From the Build panel, search for the screenElement you want to add, such as Text, Phone, or Website.
- Drag the screenElement onto the canvas, inside a Step element. You can reposition, clone, and adjust the width of the screenElement with a 12-column snap-to-grid.
- Configure the screenElement properties from the Properties panel. You can set the name, label, value, required, and other properties depending on the type of screenElement.
- Preview your script in Preview mode and test how the screenElement looks and behaves.

For more details and examples, you can refer to the [Dig into the OmniScript Designer](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/omnistudio-omniscript/dig-into-the-omniscript-designer) and Create a [Simple OmniScript](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/omnistudio-omniscript/create-a-simple-omniscript) trailhead units.

Comment: we are unable to find ScreenElement in Designer. Can you please guide how can we see and drag screenElement in canvas in the omniscript?

Comment: @AbdulRaheem, I have edited the answer and added steps.